# Can vstest.console.exe run web performance tests?

Tags: mstest, tfsbuild, vstest

I migrated my web performance tests project's build to TFS 2013 build process template for auto nuget restore by following [this document](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html).

My solution has .webtest files which are the containers for web performance tests. But VsTest.console.exe doesn't recognize the .webtest tests. I looked at the discoverers and found that none of the ones installed support the .webtest extension.

[image]

I tried to find test adapters for running .webtests using vstest.console.exe but found nothing.

[This document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) says the following for **vstest.console.exe**:

> You can run automated unit and coded UI tests from the command line.

And this for **mstest.exe**:

> You can run automated Web performance and load tests from the command line either locally or by using a test controller or test agents.

Why doesn't **vstest.console.exe** support .webtests ? Wasn't it designed as a replacement to **mstest.exe** for running any kind of tests using adapters ?

Also, if it means that I need to write a custom adapter that can read and run tests with .webtest extension, what does it take for me to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vstest.console can run webtests using the following:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" SmokeTest.orderedtest /Settings:..\..\..\local.testsettings"
```

You need to create an **orderedtest** and put your **webtest** in it.

Answer (score 0):

vstest.console can run .webtest Webtests. Enter the path to the exe in quotation marks and then the path to the webtest:

```
 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" WebTest1.webtest
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like vstest.console.exe cannot run load tests and web tests. My only option is to use MsTest.exe through TFS 2013 by customizing the build process template to suit my needs.

Edit: I'm wrong. You can run web tests using vstest.console.exe.

Comment: Raju, May I know how do you run webtests by using vstest?  I am facing the same situation.  Thanks.